# SharePoint 2013 REST display Rich Text field not working?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, html

I am using SharePoint 2013 I want to display list data with REST and Angular js

my rich text field does not show properly how can I solve it.

I have added a content editor web part

My code is:

```
<script>  


var myAngApp = angular.module('SharePointAngApp', []);  
myAngApp.controller('spCustomerController', function ($scope, $http) {  
    $http({  
        method: 'GET',  
        url: "https://MyServer/sites/testdev/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Announce')/items",  
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }  
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
        $scope.customers = data.d.results;  

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {  

    });  
});  

</script>  

<h1>My Test Heading</h1>  

<div ng-app="SharePointAngApp" class="row">  
<div ng-controller="spCustomerController" class="span10">  
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">  
        <tr>  
            <th>Title</th>   

        </tr>  
        <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">  
            <td>
            <a href="https://myserver.com/sites/testdev/Lists/Announce/DispForm.aspx?ID={{customer.ID}}">{{customer.Title}}</a>
           {{customer.Content}}

            </td>  
            </tr> 
    </table>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

the Content field is a field with multiple line of text or rich field
when I run it in my browser it shows the content field text html also:

[image]
how can I display a rich text field in its proper way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)Register [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) module:

Add reference to `angular-sanitize.js` resource, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

Include `ngSanitize` module, for example:

```
var app = angular.module('SmartphoneOSList', ['ngSanitize']);
```

2) Replace the line:

```
<td>...{{customer.Content}}</td>
```

with this one:

```
<td ng-bind-html="item.Content"></td>
```

Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10971756/1375553) for a more details.

**Complete example**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script> 
var app = angular.module('SmartphoneOSList', ['ngSanitize']);  
app.controller('ListController', function ($scope, $http) {  
    $http({  
        method: 'GET',  
        url: "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Smartphone OS')/items",  
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }  
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
        $scope.items = data.d.results;  
        $scope.displayFormUrl = "/news/Lists/SmartphoneOS/DispForm.aspx";  
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
        //...
    });  
});  
</script>  


<h1>Smartphone OSes</h1>  
<div ng-app="SmartphoneOSList">  
    <table ng-controller="ListController">   
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">  
            <td><a href="{{displayFormUrl}}?ID={{item.ID}}">{{item.Title}}</a></td>
            <td ng-bind-html="item.Content"></td>  
        </tr>  
    </table>  
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Great, glad this helped you :)

Comment: Extra feature: if i put a textbox in my page with a button how can I display results based on text box value on click of the button

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="customer.Content"></div>
```

This means you must trust the source, but as far as I know SharePoint won't let users without higher permission insert any dangerous markup.

But it's always good to be on the safe side, use [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) and:

```
<div ng-bind-html="customer.Content"></div>
```

Comment: I added the ngSanitize and modified my code like this:    <div ng-bind-html="customer.Content">{{customer.Content}}</div>

Comment: but it is not working again it shows the: <div class="ExternalClassE90D93A55B49490C8A4C63673EAA0654"> and my text

Comment: Don't do `both ng-bind-html` and {{customer.Content}}, only do the attribute

Comment: how should i add please can you right that

Comment: It should work if you copy my example above. Note that Angular version can be important, make sure you have the latest

Comment: <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="customer.Content">{{customer.Content}}</div>
<div ng-bind-html="customer.Content"></div>
   is it correct

Comment: The last `div` there should be fine, as long as you include ngSanitize and add it as a module. If it does not work check your console (web dev tools) for errors

Answer (score 0):

You are using angular js.
In angular js you can use ngSanitize which will resolve your problem and render html properly.
You can download sanitize.js from [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngSanitize)

html for description will be like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="eachProjectDependencies in ProjectDependencies|filter:drpDownFilter">                           
                        <td ng-bind-html= "eachProjectDependencies.Description"></td>
                      </tr>
```

and in your js put dependency for sanitize.js like shown below.

```
var demoApp = angular.module("demoApp",["ngSanitize"]);
```